# Apache redirect rule based on a pattern

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a virtualhost where I want to redirect all requests that start with a subdomain

```
*.admin.example.com
```

to

```
*-admin.example.com
```

Basically just replace the **Dot** with a **Dash**, and maintain URL path, parameters etc.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to convert a sub-subdomain to a hyphenated subdomain, ie. `<sub-subdomain>.admin.example.com` to `<sub-subdomain>-admin.example.com`.

You can do this using mod_rewrite directly inside your `<VirtualHost>` container:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.(admin\.example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1-%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

The above with redirect a request of the form `https://<sub-subdomain>.admin.example.com/url-path?params` to `https://<sub-subdomain>-admin.example.com/url-path?params`. The URL-path and any params on the original request are preserved through the redirect.

The `%1` and `%2` backreferences contain the captured subgroups from the preceding *CondPattern*, ie. the `<sub-subdomain>` and rest of the domain after the first dot respectively.

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path, including the slash prefix.

Any query string is passed through by default.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Change this to 301 (permanent) if that is the intention, but only once you have confirmed this works as intended - to avoid potential caching issues.